# Dealing with none dimension of symbolic tensor when creating a layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to implement my own Max Unpooling layer as explained in [here](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-convolutional-neural/9781789130331/6476c4d5-19f2-455f-8590-c6f99504b7a5.xhtml). For that, I need the `argmax` output of [tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool_with_argmax).
I successfully applied it using the layer outside any model, but when I want to add it to a model (and therefore, TensorFlow uses symbolic/static tensors, I get errors. I have tried many implementations and I came out with 2 options in summary:

- Option 1: My favorite. Give the expected output shape to the constructor (without batch size, meaning in a 2D example would be WxHxC.
- Option 2: Pass a reference tensor and imitate that shape.

In both options I have the same problem on `tf.scatter_nd`:

```
*** ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor
```

I understand why this error happens, with dynamic tensors, the batch is unknown and therefore the shape is `tf.TensorShape([None, ...])`. But how do I deal with it?

Here my implementation.

```
class UnPooling2D(Layer):

    def __init__(self, desired_output_shape, name=None, dtype=DEFAULT_COMPLEX_TYPE, dynamic=False, **kwargs):
        self.desired_output_shape = desired_output_shape    # If option 1
        super(ComplexUnPooling2D, self).__init__(trainable=False, name=name, dtype=self.my_dtype.real_dtype,
                                               dynamic=dynamic, **kwargs)

    def call(self, inputs, unpool_mat, reference_tensor_for_shape: Optional[Only if option 2], **kwargs):
        """
        Performs unpooling
        :param inputs: Input Tensor.
        :param unpool_mat: Result argmax from tf.nn.max_pool_with_argmax
            https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/max_pool_with_argmax
        """       
        updates = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1])
        indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.reshape(unpool_mat, [-1]), axis=-1)

        ####################
        # Option 1:
        flat_output_shape = tf.reduce_prod(self.desired_output_shape)
        ret = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape=(inputs.get_shape()[0]*flat_output_shape,))
        desired_output_shape_with_batch = tf.concat([[inputs.get_shape()[0]], self.desired_output_shape], axis=0)
        ret = tf.reshape(ret, shape=desired_output_shape_with_batch)

        # Option 2 (untested, speudo code):
        flatten_reference_tensor = tf.reshape(reference_tensor_for_shape, [-1])
        ret = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape=flatten_reference_tensor.get_shape())
        ret = tf.reshape(ret, reference_tensor_for_shape.get_shape())
        #################
        return ret
```

---

I tried an ugly fix but have the error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:AutoGraph could not transform <bound method UnPooling2D.call of <layers.pooling.ComplexUnPooling2D object at 0x7f95cab16220>> and will run it as-is.
```

What I tried is to do:

```
    def call(self, inputs, unpool_mat, **kwargs):
        if inputs.get_shape()[0]:
           ... other solutions
        else:   # Dynamic tensors
            ret = tf.reshape(inputs, (-1,) + self.desired_output_shape)
        return ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I partially solved the issue, but I think my new bug merits a new question actually. In the end I had to change `inputs.get_shape()` for `tf.shape(inputs)`. This is my final code that "works". (at least it gets the shape of the model right without errors in, for example, model.summary().

```
    def call(self, inputs, unpool_mat, **kwargs):
        flat_output_shape = tf.reduce_prod(self.desired_output_shape)

        updates = tf.reshape(inputs, [-1])
        indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.reshape(unpool_mat, [-1]), axis=-1)

        ret = tf.scatter_nd(indices, updates, shape=(tf.shape(inputs)[0]*flat_output_shape,))
        desired_output_shape_with_batch = tf.concat([[tf.shape(inputs)[0]], self.desired_output_shape], axis=0)
        ret = tf.reshape(ret, shape=desired_output_shape_with_batch)
        return ret
```