# Generate a partially known tensor Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I am doing a custom layer on Tensorflow. In the call function, I received the desired output shape. Basically, my last lines of code are literally:

```
desired_output_shape_with_batch = tf.concat([[tf.shape(inputs_values)[0]], output_shape], axis=0)
ret = tf.reshape(ret, shape=desired_output_shape_with_batch)
return ret
```

I use the first dimension of concat: `tf.shape(inputs_values)[0]` as the batch size and this worked correctly until now that I want to make also the desired output shape to be able to change.

For example (None, None, 3) so I can accept different RGB images.

However, the concat function says: `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (None, None, 3)`

This is not a problem I can use the [`is_fully_defined()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape#is_fully_defined) method and check at the beginning of my function if the shape is fully defined and if not just return a partially defined tensor of shape `(None, None, None, 3)`, but **how do I create this Partially defined tensor?**

Basically, my idea is to do:

```
def call(inputs, **kwargs):
    inputs_values, output_shape = inputs
    if tf.TensorShape(output_shape).is_fully_defined():
        # do my stuff
        return ret
    else:
        # output shape will be a list or set with some None values
        return tf.Tensor(shape=(None,) + output_shape)
```

How can I do that? If there is a better practice way to do this I am also open to advise.

This question is similar to [Dealing with none dimension of symbolic tensor when creating a layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66706663/dealing-with-none-dimension-of-symbolic-tensor-when-creating-a-layer) and it is actually the same layer that I want, this time, to be able to have an unknown `desired_output_shape` on the construction of the model.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. But the standard method is to pre-calcultae the output shape of your layer by implementing the `build` method of the layer, and then use the fully defined shape in your `call` method.  See the [guide](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/#best-practice-deferring-weight-creation-until-the-shape-of-the-inputs-is-known).

Comment: The problem is I don't know at build time the dimensions. For example, imagine a convolution layer that supports any dimension of images as input, this is not so crazy as the convolution is defined for any size of the image. My layer should support images of 10x10 and 20x20 for example at eval/train time, not compile time.